# Rails - Error while inserting decimal in a float column in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rounding

I have a table in development that was created with this migration:

```
class CreateMateriales < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def change
  create_table :materiales do |t|
   t.belongs_to :refaccion, index: true
   t.belongs_to :solmate, index: true
   t.integer :partida
   t.integer :pedida
   t.integer :surtida

   t.timestamps null: false
  end
 end
end
```

But then I realized I needed to store decimals on `:pedida` and `:surtida` so I did this migration:

```
class ChangeTypesPedidaSurtidaMateriales < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    change_column :materiales, :pedida, :float
    change_column :materiales, :surtida, :float
  end

  def self.down
    change_column :materiales, :pedida, :integer
    change_column :materiales, :surtida, :integer
  end
end
```

And it did the trick in development but when I pushed it to Heroku it just stores them as integers. I tracked the data and noticed that it is sent as decimals and it arrives fine but on the `INSERT_INTO` command it's rounded:

[image]

[image: Firefox's web inspector]

I also did a test in the console on Heroku and it actually saves it correctly.

[image]

Any ideas why is it getting rounded? I'm sending it asynchronously. I'm using sqlite3 in development and Postgresql in production in Heroku.

Comment: Did you run migration for production?

Comment: @HieuPham I did and they went fine but apparently it took a while (like 10 min) to actually make the change, it was strange. Now it is working as intended, thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pushed to production, ran the migrations and it didn't work at first but after some time (around 10 min) the changes were now visible. I don't know if this could be a bug on Heroku.